# Akeneo category tree UI locale override

Tags: akeneo

I have an Akeneo 2.3 running with 10 locales. 1 of the locales is our customised one called ab_AB.

When viewing the category tree in `Settings -> Categories` UI or when assigning product to categories UI, the category's label is displayed according to the locale of the logged-in user.

I would like to display the category's label value from ab_AB locale instead of the logged-in user's locale.

I have looked into `/vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/src/Pim/Bundle/EnrichBundle/Resources/views/CategoryTree` for hints of what to extend/override but not quite sure what to make of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up what happens: the tree is generated by calling [CategoryTreeController::childrenAction](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/2.3/src/Pim/Bundle/EnrichBundle/Controller/CategoryTreeController.php#L188). The [rendered twig view](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/2.3/src/Pim/Bundle/EnrichBundle/Resources/views/CategoryTree/children.json.twig) will format the categories using the Twig function `children_response`, defined in the [CategoryExtension](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/2.3/src/Pim/Bundle/EnrichBundle/Twig/CategoryExtension.php#L127).

To set your own locale, you need to override this extension in your project (extend the class and redefine the class parameter `pim_enrich.twig.category_extension.class`) and override the protected method [getLabel](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/2.3/src/Pim/Bundle/EnrichBundle/Twig/CategoryExtension.php#L444) as follows:

```
protected function getLabel(
    CategoryInterface $category,
    $withCount = false,
    $includeSub = false,
    $relatedEntity = 'product'
) {
    $category->setLocale('ab_AB');

    return parent::getLabel($category, $withCount, $includeSub, $relatedEntity);
}
```

I successfully tested it with locale `fr_FR` while my PIM was in English. Category labels were then in French, both in the `Settings → Categories` menu and the category filter of the product grid.